# Android Linear Dynamic Overlap Issue

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, dynamic-programming

I hope someone can help as i have just bout pulled all my hair out with this one

I am creating an app that allows the users to take an order from the customer.

To do this I want a button that people can press that adds another line to the order.

I think i am having a problem with the linear layouts overlapping.

here is my XML

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:text="Add Text View" 
    android:onClick="addTextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and here is my class

```
package com.example.dynamictext;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void addTextView(View view) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    // Get current Layout
    LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout1);

    // Set The sub layout
    LinearLayout subLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    subLayout.setLayoutParams(lparams);

    // Add contense of sub layout
    EditText tv=new EditText(this);
//      tv.setLayoutParams(params);
    tv.setText("test");
    tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    //Display new linear layout
    subLayout.addView(tv);
    mainLayout.addView(subLayout);


    }

}
```

i have tried setting the gravity settings but nothing that worked.

I have also made sure that the new linear layout is wrapping to the content

I am expecting each linear layout to appear under the last like lines on an invoice

any hep would e appreciated

Comment: Can you post your UI screen which you got the issue?

Comment: Do you mean a screen dump?

Comment: yes, screen shot of the issue.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fvlroumtko5riop/2013-05-13%2015.39.45.png

Comment: I had pressed the button a number of times at this point, please be aware that i have modified some parts of the code from the original post if it looks different than your expecting

Comment: See my answer below, I have updated now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` line in addTextView() method. Because it always sets the layout to the screen.

Comment: could you elaborate slightly on this. When you say container layout do you still mean a linearlayout but defined differently within the XML layout file? would i then simply create the edittext item and then add it to the container with the addView property?? Thanks again

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to help me with my problem. That worked a treat. something so simple yet so effective